# Hadoop V2.7 and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hadoop

I have set up Hadoop v2.7 in my mac and i am able to start the Hadoop daemons.

I would like to write the MR program using eclipse, i need some help to get the hadoop on my eclipse, i would like to know the jar files to be added and basic set up guide

The following is my Driver class code and i couldn't execute it

```
public class MyJobDriver extends Configured implements Tool {



    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = getConf();
        JobConf job = new JobConf(conf, MyJobDriver.class);

        Path in = new Path(args[0]);
        Path out = new Path(args[1]);
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, in);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, out);

        job.setJobName("Patent");

        job.setMapperClass(InverseMapper.class);
        //Input Split consist two values separated by ","
        //K1 and V1 type is Text
        job.setInputFormat(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);  
        job.set("key.value.separator.in.input.line",",");//Everything before the separator is the key and after is the value

        job.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);//Key and value written as string and separated by tab(default)
        //when k1 and k2 are od same type and V1 and V2 are of same type
        //we can skip job.setMapOutputKeyClass() and job.setMapOutputValueClass()
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        //jobClient communicates with the JobTrackers to start job across clusters
        JobClient.runJob(job);
        return 0;
    }
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            MyJobDriver driver = new MyJobDriver();
            System.out.println("Calling the run method");
             int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(driver, args);
             System.exit(exitCode);
    }
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: All you need to include jars from `/usr/lib/hadoop/client/` in your `Build Path`

Comment: yeah i added the jar file but in a different way, i had to navigate till hadoop folder and search for .jar files, i copied the jar to a separate directory as i couldn't find the path /usr/... from eclipse build path. It works fine now. Is there a way to do it in a simple way on Mac ?

Answer (score 0):

It is too much trouble track and retrieve the necessary jar file (there are many). Instead create a maven project in eclipse and add necessary dependencies as mentioned here https://hadoopi.wordpress.com/2013/05/25/setup-maven-project-for-hadoop-in-5mn/

Comment: Thanks shanmuga ! I haven't used maven so far, i will try this approach